# Issue with Foreign keys and columns with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create foreign keys with Entity Framework using data annotations, but according  to the migration information, EF will create all the required columns, but the one with the foreign key is not showing up like I want to, plus is creating an extra normal column.

Here are the classes that I'm using to create the tables.

```
public class Productos
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdProducto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string NombreProducto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    public string DescripcionProducto { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Tallas { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Colores { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    public string ImagenURL { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Precio { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Inventario { get; set; }

    public int IdCategoria { get; set; }
    public virtual Categorias Categorias { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DetallesCarritos> DetallesCarritos { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DetallesListasDeseos> DetallesListasDeseos { get; set; }
}
```

From the code above, the property that I want with a foreign key is `IdCategoria` which value comes from this other class:

```
public class Categorias
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdCategoria { get; set; }
              
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string NombreCategoria { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    public string DescripcionCategoria { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Productos> Productos { get; set; }
}
```

And now, the fragment of the EF migration Info:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Productos",
            columns: table => new
            {
                IdProducto = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                NombreProducto = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
                DescripcionProducto = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(MAX)", nullable: false),
                Tallas = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: true),
                Colores = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: true),
                ImagenURL = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(MAX)", nullable: false),
                Precio = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Inventario = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                IdCategoria = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                CategoriasIdCategoria = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Productos", x => x.IdProducto);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Productos_Categorias_CategoriasIdCategoria",
                    column: x => x.CategoriasIdCategoria,
                    principalTable: "Categorias",
                    principalColumn: "IdCategoria",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

From the code above, for the `Productos` table, EF will create the column `IdCategoria` as a normal column, but I want this one with foreign key. And the extra column `CategoriasIdCategoria` is the the actual column that EF is creating with the foreign key.

I tried this:

```
    [ForeignKey("IdCategoria")]
    public int IdCategoria { get; set; }
    public virtual Categorias Categorias { get; set; }
```

But I'm getting the same result.

I'm using EF Core and I'm new to it so any kind of help is appreciated. And sorry for my English.

Comment: You need to put `[ForeignKey("Categorias")]` instead. Could you please check if that works? Please check [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Locate your data annotation in the wrong position, correct your code as below:

```
public int IdCategoria { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("IdCategoria")]
public virtual Categorias Categorias { get; set; }
```

or you can use the table name to introduce foreign Key:

```
[ForeignKey("Categorias")]
public int IdCategoria { get; set; }

public virtual Categorias Categorias { get; set; }
```

for going deeper you can follow [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20ForeignKey%20attribute%20is%20used,property%20of%20a%20related%20entity.) link.
good luck.

Comment: Thank you, i used the second method. Its working now.